# How to search for nulls in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I keep on getting the error : "Value cannot be null" even if i'm checking for nulls.
This is part of my code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

           if (typeof @Model.Project.ProjectPricings.Count() != 'undefined' && 
            @Model.Project.ProjectPricings.Count())
            {
            numberOfPricings = @Model.Project.ProjectPricings.Count();
            }
            sourceCodeList =  '@Html.Raw(string.Join("", Model.SourceCodeList.Select(x => "<option></option><option value=" + x.SourceCode + ">" + x.SourceCode + "</option>")))';
            targetCodeList = '@Html.Raw(string.Join("", Model.TargetCodeList.Select(x => "<option value="+ x.TargetCode + ">" + x.TargetCode + "</option>")))';
            unitTypeCodeList = '@Html.Raw(string.Join("", Model.UnitTypeCodeList.Select(x => "<option value="+ x.UnitTypeCode + ">" + x.UnitTypeCode + "</option>")))';
            currencyList = '@Html.Raw(string.Join("", Model.CurrencyList.Select(x => "<option value="+ x.CurrencyCode + ">" + x.CurrencyCode + "</option>")))';
            serviceCodeList = '@Html.Raw(string.Join("", Model.ServiceCodeList.Select(x => "<option value="+ x.ServiceCode + ">" + x.ServiceCode + "</option>")))';
            frequencyList = '@Html.Raw(string.Join("", Model.VolumeFrequencyList.Select(x => "<option value="+ x.VolumeFrequencyDescription + ">" + x.VolumeFrequencyDescription + "</option>")))';
            @*$(document)
                .ready(function() {
                    if (@Model.Project.Id == null)  {
             addPricing();
              }
              });*@
            $('#submit-price-button').button();
            $(".date").datepicker();
            $(".combobox").SumoSelect({ search: true, searchText: 'Enter here.' });

        </script>
```

Comment: What is _`typeof @Model.Project.ProjectPricings.Count() != 'undefined'`_ supposed to do?

Comment: Are you sure in your expression `@Model.Project.ProjectPricings.Count()` each part @Model, @Model.Project and @Model.Project.ProjectPricings not equals null?

Comment: it is suppose to check if it is undefined...

Comment: You're mixing JS and Razor. Are you aware that they compile and run at completely different times?

Comment: @Bor Laze: I'm not sure, that's why i want to check. How do I do this? Thanks.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: I'm very new to this, can you show me how to do it in the correct way? Thanks.

Comment: @BYG Can you post the complete error? Which line number it is occurring? Have you tried to debug?

Comment: I'm getting the error at this line:  if (typeof @Model.Project.ProjectPricings.Count() != 'undefined' && 
            @Model.Project.ProjectPricings.Count())
            {
            numberOfPricings = @Model.Project.ProjectPricings.Count();
            }

Comment: First you have to check @Model.Project.Count != 0 then Model.ProjectPricings.Count != 0

Answer (score 0):

By your description and the comment, my understanding is that you are having trouble when checking where `@Model.Project.ProjectPricings.Count()` has value, if has value set it.

your problem is you are mixing razor and javascript code for validating - in your case, it seems logical to check directly on the server side (hence razor)

so change your code to:

```
@if (Model.Project.ProjectPricings != null)
{
    @:numberOfPricings = @Model.Project.ProjectPricings.Count();
}

// rest same
```

Comment: @BYG glad it solved your problem.  Kindly reminder, mark as answer when an answer solved your problem.